# "Invalid constant value" error when trying to define an onPressed callback to Button in Flutter CupertinoNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I simply can't define a callback function for trailing or leading properties on `CupertinoNavigationBar` inside a `CupertinoPageScaffold`. I have tried many ways but the error is the same: "Invalid constant value.". Below is a screenshot of my simple code.

[image: Code with error]

And below is the error when I hover the underlined red statement.

[image: Error message on hover]

Note that on line 32 it works fine, even the same `(){}` statement works.

My main is as follows. As you can see I am using `CupertinoApp`.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      title: "Vehicles demo",
      home: VehiclesScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm stuck in this for hours now, and simply can't solve. Similar code I found around the web didn't help either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `const` as you're not providing a `const` value to your widget. So,

Replace

```dart
navigationBar: const CupertinoNavigationBar(...)
```

with

```dart
navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(...)
```

Comment: It worked!! I can't believe I read the other answers that people were talking about a const that needs to be removed but didn't see that that was the const. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also I tried putting const on other places in that tree and it broke the function as well. I am new to dart/flutter. Can you give me a short explanation why const breaks arrow functions and other ways to reference a function?

Comment: `const` is a compile time constant, so you can't provide a const widget a non-const value. Since `onPressed` takes a dynamic function (and it is that non-const thing), you can't use it. However, a `static` method or a top-level class method which is a compile time constant can be assigned to a `const` widget.